# Align labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I am making a plot with ggplot and I am having some problems with the labels. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = prueba[prueba$Prueba=="lectura",], aes(x = año, 
                          y = Promedio, 
                          group = Tipo, 
                          color = Tipo))+
  geom_point(shape = 18,
             size = 4, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Promedio - Desviacion,
                    ymax = Promedio + Desviacion,
                    width = 0.4),
                position = position_dodge(0.9),
                size = 1.3,
                show.legend = F) +
  ylim(60,140) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#A32986",
                                "#A4589E"),
                     breaks = c("Nacional", 
                                "Sena")) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                    color = "#C6C6C6",
                                    size = 1,
                                    linetype = "solid"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1,
                                    linetype = "dashed"),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "#575756",
                              size = 13),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "#575756",
                             size = 11),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.text = element_text(color = "#575756",
                               size = 13)
    ) + geom_text(aes(label = round(Promedio)),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9),
                  hjust = -0.5,
                  size = 5,
                  color = "#575756") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("(", round(Desviacion), ")")),
            color = "#575756",
            position = position_dodge(0.9),
            hjust = -0.1,
            vjust = 2,
            size = 5) + xlab(NULL)
```

The result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0aNa.png)

As you see, the labels are not properly aligned. I would like to organize de labels, such that the upper labels are centered around the same axis as the lower labels. Does anyone know how I can do that?

My data can be reproducible by

```
structure(list(Tipo = c("Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", 
"Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", 
"Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", 
"Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Sena", 
"Sena", "Sena", "Sena", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional"), año = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"
), class = "factor"), Promedio = c(96.57, 98.03, 98.51, 100.22, 
98.17, 94.57, 98.07, 98.8, 87.38, 101.45, 99, 99.35, 96.11, 98.82, 
97.1, 95.8, 97.49, 99.86, 90.59, 97.88, 90.6, 95.13, 97.56, 98.25, 
94.03, 89.12, 91.94, 97.21, 94.77, 98.8, 99.04, 98.49, 99, 99, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 100, 98, 101, 100, 96, 100, 90, 102, 
98, 100, 100, 100, 95, 132, 92, 100, 93, 102, 146, 148, 100, 
147, 96, 95, 100, 90, 98, 93, 100, 134, 143), Desviacion = c(19.96, 
20.12, 20.27, 19.78, 19.7, 18.21, 19.85, 20.17, 29.58, 22.13, 
21.98, 19.35, 20.65, 19.78, 21.17, 25.08, 22.66, 21.62, 20.9, 
20.52, 21.32, 18.83, 19.49, 21.09, 21.46, 20.54, 23.93, 21.3, 
20.09, 26.99, 19.72, 21.3, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 22, 
23, 21, 22, 20, 28, 23, 25, 23, 22, 20, 22, 31, 21, 22, 22, 22, 
27, 28, 20, 28, 21, 21, 22, 21, 22, 25, 28, 30, 28), Prueba = c("mantenimiento", 
"lectura", "competencias", "promoción", "inglés", "ensamblaje", 
"razonamiento", "comunicación", "mantenimiento", "promoción", 
"comunicación", "lectura", "razonamiento", "inglés", "competencias", 
"ensamblaje", "competencias", "comunicación", "mantenimiento", 
"inglés", "razonamiento", "promoción", "ensamblaje", "lectura", 
"mantenimiento", "razonamiento", "competencias", "lectura", "promoción", 
"comunicación", "ensamblaje", "inglés", "competencias", "razonamiento", 
"inglés", "promoción", "comunicación", "mantenimiento", "lectura", 
"ensamblaje", "competencias", "comunicación", "inglés", "razonamiento", 
"lectura", "mantenimiento", "promoción", "ensamblaje", "competencias", 
"inglés", "ensamblaje", "promoción", "formar", "mantenimiento", 
"lectura", "razonamiento", "comunicación", "enseñar", "evaluar", 
"ensamblaje", "evaluar", "promoción", "mantenimiento", "inglés", 
"razonamiento", "lectura", "competencias", "comunicación", "formar", 
"enseñar")), row.names = c(56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 934L, 935L, 
936L, 937L, 938L, 939L, 940L, 941L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 
2040L, 2041L, 2042L, 2043L, 24800L, 24801L, 24802L, 24803L, 24804L, 
24805L, 24806L, 24807L, 68059L, 68060L, 68061L, 68062L, 68063L, 
68064L, 68065L, 68066L, 171328L, 171329L, 171330L, 171331L, 171332L, 
171333L, 171334L, 171335L, 171336L, 171337L, 171338L, 339673L, 
339674L, 339675L, 339676L, 339677L, 339678L, 339679L, 339680L, 
339681L, 339682L, 339683L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following (*note that I did not use all your aesthetics, but should be enough to get the point across for one possible way to solve this*).

**Putting the labels above at constant height**

```
ggplot(data=subset(df, Prueba=='lectura'), aes(x=año, y=Promedio, group=Tipo, color=Tipo)) +
    geom_point(shape=18, size=4, position=position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(
            ymin=Promedio-Desviacion, ymax=Promedio+Desviacion, width=0.4
        ), position=position_dodge(0.9), size=1.3, show.legend=F) +
    ylim(60,140) +
    geom_text(aes(
            label = paste0(round(Promedio), "\n(", round(Desviacion), ")"), y=100),
            vjust=-4.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)
        )
```

Giving you this:

[image]

I couldn't find a great way to align the text to the right or left of each bar.  Since you are using `position_dodge` with your dataset, you are unable to use `nudge_x`, for example, to move everything "to the right" equally.  [It's not allowed to use both in the geom](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html).  Playing with `hjust` kind of works, but you can expect funny things to occur here with the two lines as you already experienced.

Note also that I've combined your two `geom_text` calls into one, where you can just use `paste0()` or `paste()` to combine and "make your own label" on the fly.

`vjust` use across the board allows you to put them all at the same height - which I think is what you were referring to, correct?

Again - colors are different than yours, since I did not include your `scale_color_manual` and `theme` calls.

**Putting the Label to the Side, Nudged + Position_dodge**

If you want to put the labels to the side, you cannot do this with `nudge_x`, since you are unable to combine `nudge_x` and `position` arguments in `geom_text`.  A workaround is to create a new variable to use for the label aesthetic based on `df$año`, then use that in your `aes(...` call in `geom_text`:

```
df$año_new <- as.numeric(df$año) + 0.1 # nudge of "0.1". Had to force numeric, since + does not work on factors
```

Then you keep everything in the original plot call, but change only the last `geom_text` call (note the important addition of `hjust=0`, which aligns everything to the left):

```
geom_text(aes(
            x=año_new, y=100,
            label = paste0(round(Promedio), "\n(", round(Desviacion), ")")
        ),
        hjust=0,
        position=position_dodge(0.9)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Might work well to set `aes(y = Promedio+Desviacion)` inside `geom_text` rather than relying on finding a constant value that works.

Comment: That's true good point.  I found that changing `y=100` to `y=Promedio+Desviacion+5` works pretty well.  You still need the "standoff" constant value to push it above the error bar.  The only point is the OP seemed to reference that they wanted the labels to be aligned, so constant would be the best way there.

Comment: I understand what you did, and it works find. However, for the purposes of my plot, it is convenient to present the label just at the right (or left) as the point. Do you have a way to do it by using the nudge_x option? It does not matter if I have to re structured the whole code by not using position_dodge.

Comment: Problem is that `position=...` and `nudge_x=...` cannot be used together.

Comment: The other way you could do it would be kind of a hack: adding a column in your dataset `ano_new <- ano+0.2`, then using that for the `x=` aesthetic.  So your `geom_text` call would be:
`geom_text(aes(x=ano_new, label = ...`

Comment: Just tried - it works, but you might have to force `df$ano` to be numeric:
`df$ano_new <- as.numeric(df$ano) + 0.2` (I don't have the funny "n" character on my keyboard :)

Comment: That is what I meant. Is there a way to achieve what I want by removing position = .. and usinge nudge_x instead.?

Comment: You need `position=` still, because your data is plotting based on x=2016, for example (putting both of those points at x=2016).  `dodge` is working to separate them out.  I've modified the answer with another example similar to above.  Note that I used `hjust=0` to align left and found 0.1 to work here as a "nudge".  Basically, the approach is "nudge the dataset", rather than nudge in the function call.  Maybe there's a good way to "nudge" within the function call, but not from what I saw when you also need to use `position=...`.